# Updating data for a class but omitting one field (Angular, Firestore, AngularFire2)

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I want to update a few fields in my Firestore each time a user logs in. I have the following method.

```
  private updateUserData(user: firebase.User) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<AppUser> = this.afs.doc(
      `users/${user.uid}`
    );

    const data: AppUser = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      name: user.displayName
    };
    return userRef.set(data, { merge: true });
  }
```

I have a user model class like so:

```
    export class AppUser {
    uid: string;
    email: string;
    name?: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
  }
```

and i want to update everything except the isAdmin field, so I created a variable:

```
const data: AppUser = {
  uid: user.uid,
  email: user.email,
  name: user.displayName
};
```

the code works fine, but I get a compiler error that its looking for the isAdmin field. Is there any way to just omit changing the isAdmin field?

[image: Angular]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to make your `isAdmin` field optional in your AppUser class. That could be why your getting an error. Also, I might consider using an `interface` rather than a class if you just want to define the types for JS Object.

Then, to simply the omission of that field, I recommend using Lodash.

```
  import * as _ from 'lodash';


  private updateUserData(user: firebase.User) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<AppUser> = this.afs.doc(
      `users/${user.uid}`
    );

    return userRef.set(_.omit(data, 'isAdmin'), { merge: true });
  }
```

See more here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#omit

Comment: of course...i had every other field as nullable except the isAdmin. Thansk!